# PostFix Sender-based Routing with the same SMTP host but different credentials

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a postfix based mail server that I need to configure to send mail for different domains using the same SMTP server but with different AUTH settings.

Example:

- mail from domain1.com should go out via smtp.gmail.com with username1@domain.com:PASSWORD1
- mail from domain2.com should go out via smtp.gmail.com with username2@domain.com:PASSWORD2
  ...
  and so on.

I have this so far in my main.cf file:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_maps
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

And /etc/postfix/relay_maps:

```
@domain1.com [smtp.gmail.com]:587
@domain2.com [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

And /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user1@domain.com:PASSWORD1
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    user2@domain.com:PASSWORD2
```

But it does not work as expected and everything goes out using the first line of credentials from *sasl_passwd*

Basically what I can't figure out is how to make postfix differentiate which credentials set it should use for which domain.

Please help.
THanks

Answer (score 1):

I found something that worked for me at https://gist.github.com/zmwangx/2c56aa32be68daf48c2f

This is the short version of what is described.

#### Create 2 files.

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:

```
# per-sender authentication
account1@gmail.com account1@gmail.com:passwd1
account2@gmail.com account2@gmail.com:passwd2

# default relayhost
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 default_account@gmail.com:default_passwd
```

/etc/postfix/sender_relay:

```
account1@gmail.com [smtp.gmail.com]:587
account2@gmail.com [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

#### Process the files

```bash
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
postmap sasl_passwd sender_relay
```

#### add to main.cf

```
# sender-dependent sasl authentication
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay

# smtp authentication settings
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```